# Updating SWT periodically causes GUI to freeze

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

**Problem**: SWT freezes when GUI field is periodically updated.

I would like to have a SWT-based GUI with text field were values are periodically incremented.

1. Initially I accessed textField from separate Thread what led to throwing exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid
>   thread access     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:373)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2311)  at
>   regreon.Incrementing.lambda$0(Incrementing.java:62)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2. After reading SWT documentation (thanks to @marko-topolnik ) - I tried using `display.SyncExec(Runnable r)` or `display.AsyncExec(Runnable r)` with runnable that called `Thread.sleep` in the loop. But this caused the **whole thing to freeze.**
   Here is the code:

   package whatever;
   import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
   import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
   import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
   import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

   public class FreezingGUI {

   ```
   protected Shell shell;
   private Text text;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           FreezingGUI window = new FreezingGUI();
           window.open();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public void open() {
       Display display = Display.getDefault();
       createContents();
       shell.open();
       shell.layout();

       // HOW TO DO THAT???
       display.syncExec(() -> {
           while (true) {
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   Integer i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText()) + 1;
                   text.setText(i.toString());
               }
           }
       }
       );
       while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
           if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
               display.sleep();
           }
       }
   }

   protected void createContents() {
       shell = new Shell();
       shell.setSize(450, 300);
       shell.setText("SWT Application");

       text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
       text.setEditable(false);
       text.setText("0");
       text.setBounds(30, 32, 78, 26);
   }
   ```

   }

How to avoid freezing and throwing exception?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fswt_threading.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any SWT operation which changes a UI object must be run on the SWT User Interface thread.

In your case the `text.setText(i.toString());` line is an SWT UI operation and is running in a different thread.

You can use the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods of `Display` to run some code in the UI thread. So replace:

```
text.setText(i.toString());
```

with

```
final String newText = i.toString();
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> text.setText(newText));
```

(this is assuming you are using Java 8).

Using `asyncExec` will do the UI update asynchronously. Use `syncExec` instead if you want to pause the thread until the update is done.

If you are using Java 7 or earlier use:

```
 final String newText = i.toString();
 Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      text.setText(newText);
    }
 });
```

Note you should also be checking for the `Shell` being disposed and stopping your background thread. If you don't do this you will get an error when you close the app. Your code incrementing `i` is also wrong. This thread works:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 1; true; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }

        if (shell.isDisposed())  // Stop thread when shell is closed
          break;

        final String newText = Integer.toString(i);
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> text.setText(newText));
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I wanted to add updates in the loop. I tried asyncExec and SyncExec. Both freeze when i add Thread.sleep().

Comment: The Thread.sleep must **not** be in the `asyncExec` code, you must only have the `text.setText` method as I show. Putting the UI thread to sleep will cause the UI to freeze.

Comment: I updated the answer with the full code for the thread - this definitely works.

Comment: Checked and it works perfectly. Many thanks. For a newbie to SWT it is a bit new that you have to create Thread with Runnable that has another Runnable in it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the reason your UI is freezing is because you are executing a runnable on Display.sync that never returns because of the while(true) loop, as a result, other UI threads don't get a chance to execute and the UI freezes. What you need to do is use Displasy.asyncRunnable and instead of having a runnable with while(true) make a scheduler or another thread that sleeps every x seconds that executes the runnable to make the update you want, this way the other UI threads can run preventing your UI from freezing.