# Java: Invalid thread access - pop up menu

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Within an eclipse plugin I am trying to create a pop up window that activates within an editor and adds syntax to a string depending on the selection chosen in the pop up window. I have an editor class that extends AbstractTextEditor and within it I am trying to use a keylistener to pop up a window that contains a list of string manipulation functions and then when an item in the list is selected I want to replace some selected content with the new string returned from the method in the pop up window. When I attempt to do this (with the code in the 2 linked files), I receive the error below:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException:
>   Invalid thread access
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4595)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4510)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4481)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:451)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:369)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getSelectionRange(StyledText.java:4743)
>       at githubflavoredmarkdowneclipseplugin.MarkdownEditor.test(MarkdownEditor.java:140)
>       at autocomplete.AutoComplete$1.keyPressed(AutoComplete.java:50)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

It seems that when autoupdate class tries to inform the editor class that a change has been selected it cannot manipulate the styledText variable. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The two files that contain this code can be reviewed at these links:
http://www.filedropper.com/markdowneditor
http://www.filedropper.com/autocomplete

Comment: Code that you want us to look at must be **here** in the question as a [mcve]. In general you can ony do UI actions in the main SWT UI thread, doing them in any other thread gives this error. Read about `Display.asyncExec` and `Display.syncExec` as for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40265720/2670892). It looks like you are mixing Swing with SWT - this is very hard to do well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that exception is because when you make changes that are UI related with SWT you have to execute a runnable vis Display.syncExec(myRunable) otherwise that exception will occur.